# Why does a particular model cause migrations every time I use `makemigrations`?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Django application called "proxy". It's `models.py` content looks like this:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models


class Proxy(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u"Прокси"
        verbose_name_plural = u"Прокси"

    TYPE = ((1, "http"), (2, "socks4"), (3, "socks5"))

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=u'Прокси')
    label = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=u'Лейбл')
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=u"IP")
    port = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=u'Порт')
    login = models.CharField(
        max_length=200, verbose_name=u'Логин', null=True, blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(
        max_length=200, verbose_name=u'Пароль', null=True, blank=True)
    kind = models.IntegerField(
        verbose_name='Тип Прокси', default=1, choices=TYPE)
    expiration_date = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name="Срок окончания валидности", null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class ProxyList(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Лист"
        verbose_name_plural = "Листы"

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=u'Название листа')
    alias = models.SlugField(max_length=300, verbose_name=u'Адрес листа')
    proxies = models.ManyToManyField(Proxy, verbose_name=u'Прокси')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

The problem I am facing is that, every time I try to run `makemigrations`, it creates meaningless migration files, as shown below:

**makemigrations output:**

```
Migrations for 'proxy':
  proxy/migrations/0112_auto_20191110_1658.py
    - Alter field proxies on proxylist
Migrations for 'serversettings':
  serversettings/migrations/0052_auto_20191110_1658.py
    - Alter field top50_proxy on serversettings
Migrations for 'top50':
  top50/migrations/0066_auto_20191110_1658.py
    - Alter field proxy on scriptproxy
```

**generated migration file:**

```
# Generated by Django 2.2.1 on 2019-11-10 13:58

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('proxy', '0111_auto_20191110_1640'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='proxylist',
            name='proxies',
            field=models.ManyToManyField(to='proxy.Proxy', verbose_name='Прокси'),
        ),
    ]
```

Related models migration files are just `AlterField`'s with the same parameters I specified in their `Proxy` relationship field.

I don't really know what could cause this. My django settings file does not mention anything specific related to the `proxy` application. Maybe it's a naming issue I don't know anything about? Is there a reserved list of Django application names I shouldn't use (like proxy, for example)?

How to get rid of these "automatic migrations"?

Comment: Do all the other migrations have the exactly same content?

Comment: @heemayl related models have `AlterField` for their particular case (e.g. copied from the related model field definition). Each time I run `makemigrations`, only the django "created" date comment changes.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try to change proxies definition as it done in the migration file:

```
field=models.ManyToManyField(to='proxy.Proxy', verbose_name='Прокси')
```

As you say proxy may have a special meaning and Django might try to change the definition to avoid a conflict.

Comment: It does not change anything really. I've tried it and the same thing happens.